# Traverse an STD Class object inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've send an Array with data through FormData with Ajax. 
I json encoded it first before sending it through and decoded it back at the PHP side.

My problem is this: `"Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object"` Or `"Illegal string offset ID"`

which is weird, since my array is like:

```
 array(7) {
 [0]=>
 object(stdClass)#779 (2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(19) "Onbeperkt helpdesk."
 }
 [1]=>
 object(stdClass)#780 (2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(43) "Een direct aanspreekpunt voor al uw vragen."
 }
 [2]=>
 object(stdClass)#781 (2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(20) "Een stabiel netwerk."
 }
 [3]=>
 object(stdClass)#782 (2) {
    ["ID"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(43) "Uw belangrijke gegevens optimaal beveiligd."
 }
}
```

The way I tried traversing the array:

```
 $voordelen = json_decode($_POST['voordelen']);
                        echo var_dump($voordelen);
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($voordelen); $i++) {
                            foreach ($voordelen[$i] as $key => $item) {
                                $voorArray = array(
                                    "id" => $item->ID,
                                    "item" => $item->Value,
                                    "content_id" => $content->id // variable from code not shown here.
                                );
                            }
                        }
```

I also tried:

```
                            for ($i = 0; $i < count($voordelen); $i++) {
                            foreach ($voordelen[$i] as $item) {
                                $voorArray = array(
                                    "id" => $item->ID,
                                    "item" => $item->Value,
                                    "content_id" => $content->id // Variable from code not shown here.
                                );
                            }
                        }
```

I also tried using `$var['value']` instead of `$var->value`

But now I'm at a loss. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($key, $item)`…!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making an extra loop, did you try:

```
foreach ($voordelen as $item) {
    $voorArray = array(
        "id" => $item->ID,
        "item" => $item->Value,
        "content_id" => $content->id // Variable from code not shown here.
    );
    var_dump($voorArray);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I really feel like I fooled myself for the past hour.. I thought I tried it like this before. But I guess that was before encoding and decoding the array.. Thanks though!

Comment: No problem... That kind of stuff will happen again and again, if you get stuck on a problem like this one for one hour, just take a break :)

Comment: Yeah, that's some advice I am going to take :). Stumping my head against a wall didn't really work afterall :P. Will mark as answer when the answertimer is done.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with just looping through it, since `$voordelen` is already an array:

```
$voordelen = json_decode($_POST['voordelen']);

foreach( $voordelen as $item )
{
    $voorArray = array(
        "id"         => $item->ID,
        "item"       => $item->Value,
        "content_id" => $content->id 
    );

    // Do something with $voorArray here.
}
```

Comment: Oh, I really feel like I fooled myself for the past hour.. I thought I tried it like this before. But I guess that was before encoding and decoding the array.. Thanks though!